# Почему когда я вставляю второй код js то получается каша. Кто знает как сделайте, пожалуйста, что бы селект меню открывалось как на картинке

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Currency Converter</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Untitled-1.css">
  <script src="main.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="charity__currencies">
        <a class="exchange__rates">Курси валют</a>     
  <div class="custom-select" style="width:140px;">
    <select id="currencySelect">
      <option value="0">У відділенях</option>
      <option value="1">У відділенях</option>
      <option value="2">Для карток</option>
      <option value="3">НБУ</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="rates">
    <a class="eur">EUR</a>
    <a class="uan__buy">UAN</a>
    <a class="usd">USD</a>
    <a class="uan1__buy">UAN</a>
    <a class="pln">PLN</a>
    <a class="uan2__buy">UAN</a>
    <a class="purchase">Купівля</a>
    <a id="eur__buy-price" class="eur__buy-price">39.85</a>
    <a id="eur__sell-price" class="eur__sell-price">40.85</a>
    <a id="usd__buy-price" class="usd__buy-price">37.1</a>
    <a id="usd__sell-price" class="usd__sell-price">37.6</a>
    <a id="pln__buy-price" class="pln__buy-price">8.77</a>
    <a id="pln__sell-price" class="pln__sell-price">9.35</a>
    <a class="sell">Продаж</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>




body{
  background-color: #D9D9D9;
}
    
#currencySelect{
    border: none;
    margin-left: 2vw;
    margin-top: 0.6vh;
}

.exchange__rates{
  padding: 25px;
}

.charity__currencies{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 35px;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vh;
}
  
    .sell{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 8vh;
    margin-left: 11vw;
}

.purchase{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 8vh;
    margin-left: 4vw;
}

.eur{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 12vh;
    margin-left: -11vw;
}

.uan__buy{
    color: #DFE1E1;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 12vh;
    margin-left: -7vw;
}

.usd{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 19vh;
    margin-left: -11vw;
}

.uan1__buy{
    color: #DFE1E1;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 19vh;
    margin-left: -7vw;
}

.pln{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 26vh;
    margin-left: -11vw;
}

.uan2__buy{
    color: #DFE1E1;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 26vh;
    margin-left: -7vw;
}

.eur__buy-price{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 12vh;
    margin-left: 4vw;
}

.eur__sell-price{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 12vh;
    margin-left: 11vw;
}

.usd__buy-price{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 19vh;
    margin-left: 4vw;
}

.usd__sell-price{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 19vh;
    margin-left: 11vw;
}

.pln__buy-price{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 26vh;
    margin-left: 4vw;
}

.pln__sell-price{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 26vh;
    margin-left: 11vw;
}

.rates{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 11vw;
    margin-top: -4.5vh;
    padding: 5px 25px;
}

.custom-select {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
  }

  .select-selected:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 14px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-color: #93989d transparent transparent transparent;
  }
  
  .select {
    position: absolute;
    width: 7.5vw;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 10.3vh;
    margin-left: -20vw;
  }
  
  .option {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .custom-select {
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: -1vw;
    margin-top: 1vh;
  }
  
  .select-selected:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 14px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-color: #93989d transparent transparent transparent;
  }
  
  /* .select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
    border-color: transparent transparent #93989d transparent;
    top: 7px;
  } */
  
  .select-items div,.select-selected {
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
  
    border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .select-items {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    top: 100%;

    margin: 3px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.23);
  }
  


  .custom-select select {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  
  .custom-select select option {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
    color: #7ED957 !important; 
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#eur__credit{
    display: none;
}




// Add an event listener to the select element
  document.getElementById('currencySelect').addEventListener('change', function() {
    // Get the selected option value
    var selectedOption = this.value;

    // Update currency values based on the selected option
    if (selectedOption === '2') { // Для карток
      document.getElementById('eur__buy-price').textContent = '38.939';
      document.getElementById('eur__sell-price').textContent = '40.816';
      document.getElementById('usd__buy-price').textContent = '36.264';
      document.getElementById('usd__sell-price').textContent = '37.453';
      document.getElementById('pln__buy-price').textContent = '8.95';
      document.getElementById('pln__sell-price').textContent = '9.267';
      // Update other currency values accordingly
    } else {
      // Reset the values to their default if another option is selected
      document.getElementById('eur__buy-price').textContent = '39.85';
      document.getElementById('eur__sell-price').textContent = '40.85';
      document.getElementById('usd__buy-price').textContent = '37.1';
      document.getElementById('usd__sell-price').textContent = '37.6';
      document.getElementById('pln__buy-price').textContent = '8.77';
      document.getElementById('pln__sell-price').textContent = '9.35';
      // Reset other currency values accordingly

      if (selectedOption === '3') { // Для карток
      document.getElementById('eur__buy-price').textContent = '39.39';
      document.getElementById('eur__sell-price').textContent = '39.39';
      document.getElementById('usd__buy-price').textContent = '36.26';
      document.getElementById('usd__sell-price').textContent = '36.26';
      document.getElementById('pln__buy-price').textContent = '8.96';
      document.getElementById('pln__sell-price').textContent = '8.96';
      // Update other currency values accordingly
    } else {
      // Reset the values to their default if another option is selected
      document.getElementById('eur__buy-price').textContent = '39.85';
      document.getElementById('eur__sell-price').textContent = '40.85';
      document.getElementById('usd__buy-price').textContent = '37.1';
      document.getElementById('usd__sell-price').textContent = '37.6';
      document.getElementById('pln__buy-price').textContent = '8.77';
      document.getElementById('pln__sell-price').textContent = '9.35';
      // Reset other currency values accordingly
    }
    }
  });
```

Вот код при котором все как на картинке, но при выборе пункта селект меню ничего не меняется

```
let x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
l = x.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  ll = selElmnt.length;
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        let y, i, k, s, h, sl, yl;
        s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        sl = s.length;
        h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
        for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
          if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
            s.selectedIndex = i;
            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
            yl = y.length;
            for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
              y[k].removeAttribute("class");
            }
            this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
            break;
          }
        }
        h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    closeAllSelect(this);
    this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
    this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  let x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  xl = x.length;
  yl = y.length;
  for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);


const currencyTypeSelect = document.querySelector("#currency-type");
```

[image: То как должно получится селект меню показано на картинке]

```
введите сюда код
```

Comment: Что значит *"получается каша"*? А какой из всей этой кашй - "второй код", а какой первый?

Comment: Смотрите весь первый  код который я вставил включает в себя html css js где все нормально работает, но селект меню не стилизирован второй код после фразы "Вот код при котором все как на картинке, но при выборе пункта селект меню ничего не меняется" собственно добавляет эту стилизацию что б било как на картинки, но если будет и первый и второй js то они налезают все один на одного и механика js в первом коде(он выполняет функцию чтобы при выборе пункта меню менялись данные валют)не работает(нужно сделать чтоб работал и первый код js и второй(который стилизирует как на фото)) работали вместе.